# how to extract object array(results) from iron ajax response object

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer-1.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWSit.png)below code snippet for getting json data from iron ajax call . i am able to get json object value in mapResponse.
i want to get the value of results array which is in json data and want to pass this results object value in another polymer component as a input attribute

code for loading data from iron ajax

```
<iron-ajax
      id="originalData"
      auto
      url="{{originalDataURL}}"
      handle-as="json"
      last-response="{{originalData}}" on-response="mapResponse">
    </iron-ajax>


Json file


{
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "results": [
        {
          "groups": [
            {
              "name": "type",
              "type": "number"
            }
          ],
          "values": [
            [
              946890000000,
              99.93584833,
              3
            ],
            [
              946846800000,
              99.94809842,
              3
            ],
            [
              946803600000,
              99.96034846,
              3
            ],
            [
              946760400000,
              99.97259848,
              3
            ],
            [
              946717200000,
              99.98484848,
              3
            ]
          ],
          "attributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "stats": {
        "rawCount": 5
      }
    }
  ]
}


 <script>
    Polymer({
 is: 'test-view',
 properties: {
 results: {
        type: Array
      },

     mapResponse: function (data) {
        var dummy = data.detail.response;
        console.log("resposne is ",dummy);
        results = dummy.results;
        console.log("array is ",results);
},
```

i tried to get results array object value as above in console logs but getting undefined. here i am able to get the value of dummy where i am getting full json object (tags)  i want to get only results array object from this (tags )object .

can anyone please suggest me how can i get only results array value ??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of dummy, if its string then do `dummy=JSON.parse(dummy)`. below `var dummy = data.detail.response;`

Comment: dummy is Array where we getting data on console in this way as attached dummy response screenshot. i want results array object from this dummy object .

Comment: Are you able to log dummy? What is the `typeof(data)`

Comment: yes i am able to log dummy  its a array object as i am getting this while logging   console.log("resposne is ",dummy); --- --  resposne is  {tags: Array(1)}

Comment: i have attached screenshot link to get more what i am getting in dummy https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWSit.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `results = dummy.tags[0].results;`
instead of `results = dummy.tags[0].results;`.

Or you can do `results = dummy.tags.map(x=>x.results);` if tags have multiple arrays of results.

Comment: Thanks vibhor i am able to get the value of results  previously i was passing to whole orginaldata json object to polymer component for that i was passing this way original-data="[[orignalData]]'' because previously we have list of arrays in json now we have whole json object array as above json file so now i am passing this results value in originalData as this way original-data = "[[results]]" in that polymer component its not able to populate the value in original-data.

Comment: You can refer to your image description. Dummy was an object, tasks was a property of object which itself was array. Now you can iterate over the array to get the results(using map or loop) or if it just have a single element access that.

Comment: the two lines are identical: what so you mean with "It should be results = dummy.tags[0].results; instead of results = dummy.tags[0].results;."